# Android OnCreateOptionsMenu NOT displaying on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, menu, sdk

I try to add an option menu to my app.

```
 public static final int MENU_AIDE = Menu.FIRST+1;
 public static final int MENU_CONTACT = Menu.FIRST+2;
 public static final int MENU_APROPOS = Menu.FIRST+3;
 public static final int MENU_QUITTER = Menu.FIRST+4;

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_AIDE, Menu.NONE, "Aide").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_aide);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_CONTACT, Menu.NONE, "Nous Contacter").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_contact);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_APROPOS, Menu.NONE, "A propos").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_apropos);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_QUITTER, Menu.NONE, "Quitter").setIcon(R.drawable.menu_quitter);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case MENU_AIDE:     Toast.makeText(this,"aide",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return (true); //add(); return(true);

        case MENU_CONTACT:  Toast.makeText(this,"contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return (true);

        case MENU_APROPOS:  Toast.makeText(this,"à propos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return (true);

        case MENU_QUITTER:  Toast.makeText(this,"quitter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return (true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

BUT the menu does not display on my tablet, whereas it is ok on my emulator when clicking the "menu" buton. The onCreateOptionsMenu function is not even launched(??) on the tab!!

I just do not know why not on the tablet since both run under 4.1.

I figured out that removing the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

makes the menu displays also on my tab..........

But why?
And how solve it, I mean how keep the min & target SDK flag AND make the option menu buton visible on my tablet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set targetSdkVersion to 8 and the menu button should work on all devices.
The menu button is deprecated on newer Sdk, and if you set sdk version 11+, the button appears as a software button, but it doesn't work.

edited: menu button "doesn't work" since api 11.

Comment: Ok, I tried, and it works........ BUT I don't understand something: it is WEIRD to set the target to android 2.* as you design a 3.* & 4.* software(????), isn't it?

Comment: If you design an app for 3.* 4.*, then you should consider adding an actoin bar to your layout. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Ok, but will an action bar be compatible with 2.* apps? Or do I absolutely have to separate 2.* app & 3.* + 4.* app?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you do this. There are some libraries that make the action bar compatible on all devices (systems). I've found that support library v4 doesn't actually support action bar, but there are some workarounds: [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) You could also try [Actionbar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/). If I helped you, acceptance of my answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think the big issue here is WHY the problem only seems to occur on this specific tablet, the Galaxy Tab 10.1. We have a lot more tablets with 4.0, 4.1, 4.3 and in none of them the menu item dissapear.

Comment: This might be the only tablet that checks target sdk. It is really weird, that changing target sdk worked.